# Need help understanding x.length and array output

Tags: java

New to Java; I'm curious as to what's going on with the way this simple array example works. Specifically how the "for" statement and x.length work.

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    increase(x);

    int[] y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    increase(y[0]);

    System.out.println(x[0] + " " + y[0]);
}

public static void increase(int[] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i]++;
    }
}

public static void increase(int y) {
    y++;
}
```

}

Comment: What don't you understand? What did you research reveal?

Comment: as a side note: the method `increase(int)` won't do anything, since the int y is copied and the increase is performed on the copy, but the source will not be changed (thus `y[0]` will still be 1 after calling `increase(y[0])`

Comment: I don't understand why the output is  "2 1". Y increments once for every time x increments twice?

Comment: Not true. Nothing in `y` is being incremented. When `increase(y[0])` is called you are passing the integer 1, which is what is stored in `y[0]`, so since the parameter is an integer this method will be called `public static void increase(int y)`, which will take the number 1 and increment it to 2, BUT the statement `y++` does nothing to what is stored in `y[0]` therefore when `y[0]` gets printed it is still just a `1`.

Comment: Also, I think you are misinterpreting the `y++`, which really just means take `y` and add 1 to it. This statement, `y = y+1;` is equivalent to `y++;`. Same goes for the `x[i]++;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why the output is 2, 1 is that array is a reference variable. when calling x's increase, the parameter is x array itself. that's why x[0] is actually increased. but when calling y's increase, the parameter is just y[0] which is not a reference type but just an integer and so, the actual value of y[0] is not changed at all.

I hope it'd be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i]++;
}
```

This `for` loop will loop through the array `x` starting at element 0 until it reaches the end of it, which is it's length, denoted by `x.length`. On each pass it will increment the contents of `x[i]`. So at the end of the `for` loop `x` will contain `{2,3,4,5,6}`.